# C/C++ app on Android tablet

Tags: android, c, adb, cross-compiling

I'm porting a program from Ubuntu to android. Before trying the real porting, I wrote a simple helloworld.c and compiler it with arm Linux crosscompiler (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc). I compiled it successfully and I pushed it into my tablet with adb push command into /data directory. Using adb shell, I could rum it and it works fine. How can I show my helloworld with the other apps in my tablet? Where should I push it to let the tablet see it as an app and display to with other ones? Or should I use another adb command or anything else? Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Download the android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and take a look at the samples folder

Comment: Is it the only way? I saw in NDK I have to write the main in Java, but I need to use my c source code with no changes. I need an approach similar to adb push and runnong on adb console.

Comment: you can skip java alltogether by using a [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). Also you need to package your code as an APK file or else it wont show as an app on the homescreen

Comment: Ok, so I Won't use arm-Linux-gnueabi-gcc, I'll just create a project with NDK using a nativeActivity, right?

Comment: absolutely. You might also find the [Sequoya](http://www.aton.com/integrating-the-android-ndk-c-native-support-into-eclipse-using-sequoyah/) plugin useful